# Не могу настроить работу Selenium на сервере linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, vds

На локальной машине работает скрипт на Python, на VDS на linux отказывается видеть `chromedriver`.

`xvfb` установлен, `selenium` установлен, Python2.7 установлен, путь до хромдрайвера указан.

Код такой:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/selenium/Drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://google.com')
ff = open("file.txt", "w")
ff.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
ff.close()
driver.close()
```

Перед отправкой меняю строчку с путем до хромдрайвера как на сервере:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/Selenium/Drivers/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://google.com')
ff = open("file.txt", "w")
ff.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
ff.close()
driver.close()
```

Отправляю это добро на сервер. 
Хромдрайвер действительно находится по указанному мной пути:

```
root@70678:/home# ls
chromedriver
```

Запускаю скрипт и получаю:

```
  File "start.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что это значит, и в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Запустите руками такую же команду, которая из скрипта выполняется. Ошибки нет? Если нет, то смотрите в переменные окружения и права доступа, если есть, то разбирайтесь по ходу выяснения причин.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение помогло и мне!

Answer (score 2):

Огромное спасибо за подсказку. В процессе дебага очень помогла поступенчатая работа с питоном в терминале.
В итоге мой код видоизменился и он действительно работает на VDS под управлением ubuntu 16...:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
ff = open("file.txt", "w")
ff.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
ff.close()
driver.close()
vdisplay.stop()
```

Очень помог код из комментария:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700657/7803940

**Для всех страждущих пишу памятку для настройки selenium+chromedriver при работе на python на vds (Виртуальном Сервере):**

1. Установить хром на VDS | обязательно наличие самого браузера в системе
2. Установить pip на vds | помогает легко устанавливать доп. пакеты python
3. Скачать chromedriver | Не забудьте скачать cromedriver
4. Установить selenium  | Селениум в python ставится с помощью pip
5. Установить виртуальный экран linux Xvfb | ставится в терминале apt-get...итд
6. Установить xvfbwrapper в питон | pip install xvfbwrapper

Comment: Ещё помогает установка интерактивного питона *ipython*, например.